# Finding screen resolutions without $DISPLAY through python or shell scripting

Tags: linux, monitors, display

I am developing a personal project/idea for a headless Raspberry Pi that works without a GUI display. I am working on a text graphicsesque design.

As the Raspberry Pi allows one to plug into most any screen, I want to be able to determine the screens resolution so I can create an optimal display.

My problem lies in actually getting the screens resolution. I have tried a few methods in python, such as messing with `xrandr` and the the Tkinter module, but both have the same problem. There technically isn't a screen, just a console.
Text editors like vim seem to be able to fit themselves without any problem.

Can I get a screens resolution, without having to load up a display?
All suggestions welcome, but my proficiencies are in the Python, C++, Java and Bash range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look in `/sys/class/drm/card*/*/modes`:

```
for card in /sys/class/drm/card*/* ; do
    echo "$card: $(head -n 1 $card/modes)"
done
```

should output something like

```
/sys/class/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1: 1024x768
/sys/class/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1: 1280x1024
```

Comment: Ive also found stty useful "os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split" . It gives you the consoles row, column value without having to rely on /drm/card, as I've noticed this is missing in my vm version of crunchbang for some reason